# continuous function in a topological space

Tags: general-topology, continuity

It is known that if $f, g$ are continuous functions then $f+g$ is also continuous.

I want to know how to prove it in topological language, thst is, $f$ is continuous if for any $x$ and any open neighbourhood $V$ containing $f(x)$, there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ so that $U\subseteq f^{-1}(V)$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First of all, you need to specify the codomain of $f,g$. I assume it is $\Bbb R$, but it could also be $\Bbb C$ or some vector space, or even more general, any topological group.

Comment: $\{ (x,y) \in X \times X | (f(x) + g(y)) \in V \} = \bigcup_x \{ y \in X | (f(x) + g(y)) \in V\}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

Suppose you have continuous functions
$$X\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}Y$$
$$X\stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow}Y$$
$$Y\times Y\stackrel{h}{\longrightarrow}Z$$

(1) Show that the first two functions induce a continuous function
$$X\stackrel{f\times g}{\longrightarrow}Y\times Y$$

(2) Show that the composition $h\circ (f\times g)$ is a continuous function $$X\stackrel{h\circ (f\times g)}{\longrightarrow}Z$$

In your case, $h$ is addition, and the spaces $Y$ and $Z$ are probably $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 0):

Given an open neighborhood $V$ containing $f(x)$ and an open neighborhood $W$ containing $g(x)$, we have $V+W$ a set containing (f+g)(x).

Now clearly $U \subset f^{-1}(V)\cap g^{-1}(W)\subset (f+g)^{-1}(V+W)$, so really all we need to show is that $V+W$ is itself open.

To clarify, $V+W=\{y:y=v+w, v\in V, w\in W \}$.

But then it follows readily that for every $w\in W$, $V+w \subset V +W$ is an open set.

Likewise for every $v\in V$, $v+W \subset V+W$.

This is because the sets are just translations of open sets, they are again open (at least for non-pathological topological spaces, see [here](http://math.arizona.edu/~laetsch/425121/TranslationFacts.pdf)).

So $V+W = \bigcup_{(v\in V,w\in W)} (v+W \cup V+w)$ is open (since arbitrary unions of open sets are again open).